# Need to implement leveler in a View of Androird?

Tags: android, android-widget

i need to implement the leveler in view of my application , where as i have the code for the leveler provided by the google. i need to implement it in my app.

This is main.xml of bubble leveler,

```
<net.androgames.level.view.LevelView 
    android:id="@+id/level"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

how can i embed this project View in to my application view.

Answer (score 1):

i think, you can simply set this view in your activity using:

```
setContentView(yourLevelViewObject);
```

OR if you want to add this view to any layout then you can use:

```
yourLayoutObject.addView(yourLevelViewObject);
```